# SwiftUI: Gradient background on List

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Can someone tell me how to add a gradient background on SwiftUI List?

Current code:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.purple]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
            .overlay(
                List {
                    Group {
                        Text("Hallo")
                        Text("World")
                    }
                    .background(Color.blue)
                }
                .background(Color.green)
                .padding(50)
        )
    }
}
```

Current layout, where the gradient is visible behind the cells. I want to make the cells transparent to see the gradient underneath.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have already added the gradient. Just make background colors clear and get rid of those test codes ;)

#### iOS 16

You can hide the background of any scrollable content using `scrollContentBackground(.hidden)` modifier

#### iOS 15 and below

You should hide the default list background and all cell's using the `appearance` property of the `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell`

Also you can hide the cell background using `.listRowBackground(.clear)`

### Example

```
struct TestView: View {

    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.purple]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
            .overlay(
                List {
                    Group {
                        Text("Hallo")
                        Text("World")
                    }
                }
                .padding(50)
        )
    }
```