# Giving a List a background (gradient) in AppKit

Tags: macos, swiftui, appkit, swiftui-list

I want to make a gradient to a `List` in SwiftUI. Obviously, it doesn't work, because the cells have their own background and I need to make the background clear. I found out how to do this on iOS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58582645/2062613).

But does anyone know how to do it with AppKit? There is no `NSTableView.appearance()`.

**UPDATE**

I made a code example:

```
var body: some View {
    List() {
        Text("First")
        Text("Second")
        Text("Third")
    }
    .background(Color.red)
}
```

The `List` doesn't get a different background.

Comment: In AppKit world there is backgroundColor for NSScrollView and NSTableView. No need to have appearance wrapper

Comment: And how do I apply that? I updated the code with an example code

Comment: @Lupurus any luck with this? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @hundley: unfortunately not. I don't think, that it's acutally possible, because the `List` creates a ScrollView and a TableView. There is no way to access either the ScrollView nor the TableView

Comment: Trying to achieve the same, how frustrating... If anyone finds a solution, please post...